# Jsoup error with get() in Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to use Jsoup 1.6.0 in my Android application, but for some reason it crashes. I simplified my code to:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class JsoupTestActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            Document d = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I run the above on my phone (in USB debugging mode) or on the emulator, I get the message that my program has unexpectedly crashed--an error wasn't even caught. If I replace the contents of the try block with

```
 Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com");
```

the program works fine, so it seems like the get() method is causing the problems...

FYI, in my AndroidManifest.xml I did include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in the correct place, and R.layout.main is the default layout that the ADT generates when you create a new project. I'm using Android API level 7 for this project. How do I get this to work?

Comment: The connect syntax is OK, but what are you importing?
I can´t see Jsoup imports, that would help a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download new version of [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download) and paste jsoup-1.6.x.jar in **libs** folder from your project.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do Network operations from the UI thread, so you should take the JSoup.connect() out of your onCreate() and use an ASyncTask